# JPA - Refresh detatched entity before setting values and persisting

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I have an detatched entity and want to set some values. But before that I want to refresh the entity to be sure to have the latest data from the database. I came up with this code. It merges and refreshes my entity before setting some new values.

The problem is, that this creates a new object. Is there a better and simpler way to archieve this?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{


    public void setValueAndPersist(){

        EntityManager em = ...

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        MyEntity newEntity = em.merge(this);

        em.refresh(newEntity);

        newEntity.setSomeVal("someVal");

        em.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know that the entity exists in thh DB, you can look it up: 
`MyEntity entity = em.find(MyEntity.class, primary-key-here);`
Then update the values - i.e. - you skip the merge/refresh stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a own class for interaction with database. DONT do this in the entity itself!

 *Solution1:*
You can use `@Version` for current object. https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/07/30/jpa-20-concurrency-and-locking . You get a Exception when its not the newest version and you tried to merge it.

  *Solution2:*
You can use `find(...)` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29

With class and ID from the current Item to load the actual state from DB (or  Persistence Context if already exists in it).

Comment: Did not know about the optimistic locking via @Version until now. Very helpful answer!